# NiFi backup restore not working since bootstraf.conf file not writable

Tags: permissions, devops, backup, apache-nifi, restore

Using Ni-Fi Toolkit to take backup of the current Ni-Fi deployment. Whenever i want to restore the backup getting such error:

```js
bash-4.4$ ./file-manager.sh -o restore -b /tmp/nifi_bak/nifi_backup_2024-02-22 -r /opt/nifi/nifi-current/ -c /opt/nifi/nifi-current/ -m -v

[main] INFO org.apache.nifi.toolkit.admin.filemanager.FileManagerTool - Restoring to directory:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/

File parameter 'destFile is not writable: '/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/bootstrap.conf'
```

I dont have root or sudo rights inside the pod. So chmod is not working.

Filesystem inside the pod is like that:

```js
sda      8:0    0   300G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0     1M  0 part
├─sda2   8:2    0   127M  0 part
├─sda3   8:3    0   384M  0 part
└─sda4   8:4    0 299.5G  0 part /opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/bootstrap.conf
sr0     11:0    1   1.1G  0 rom
```

I tried to mount and umount with write premisions but it didnt work since i dont have root rights:

```js
bash-4.4$ mount -o remount,rw '/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/'
```

Im stucked at this point. Is there any idea to deal with this issue? All i need is restoring my backup successfully.

Regards.